# how/where to set --fast mode for jruby when using it within jruby/rack inside tomcat?

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails, jruby-rack

how/where to set --fast mode for jruby when using it within jruby/rack inside tomcat?

This --fast mode is explained in this page
[jruby performance tuning](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/PerformanceTuning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass these flags to JVM:

```
-Djruby.compile.mode=FORCE -Djruby.compile.fastest=true
```

however you with Tomcat.